# Detection of Objects on Remote VM, like start button, cmd prompt using hotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

I am able to take remote control of any *virtual machine* using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) . I want to run `ipconfig` command on remote machine. It can be performed using mouse clicks, but I want to do it using **keyboard hotkeys**, can anybody help me in doing so.

Comment: Are you running AutoHotkey on the host or in the virtual machine?

Comment: I am using AutoHotKey on the host.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>, `ipconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for an AutoHotkey solution, here is a script which strictly follows your example:

```
;Hotkey, e.g. #i::
Run, cmd
WinWaitActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
Send, ipconfig{Enter}
Exit
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me how to define ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass in ahk script? does this class define information about remote machine. and Will it help to read files on remote machine?